# What type returns table in R?

Tags: r, types

I wrote this lines of code below.
I want to get the most frequent value in matrix:

```
 matrix7 <- matrix(sample(1:36, 100, replace = TRUE), nrow = 1)
    t <- table(matrix7)
    print(t)
    a <- which.max(table(matrix7))
    print(unlist(a))
```

it prints this:

```
> matrix7 <- matrix(sample(1:36, 100, replace = TRUE), nrow = 1)

> t <- table(matrix7)

> print(t)

matrix7
 1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 34 35 36 
 4  5  1  5  2  5  1  3  1  4  2  2  2  5  5  1  3  7  2  3  2  3  2  1  4  4  2  2  2  5  2  5  3 
> a <- which.max(table(matrix7))

> print(unlist(a))

19 
18 
>
```

What type is my `t` variable and `a` variable,
and how can I get the most frequent value from matrix?

Comment: Just as a side issue, you probably don't want to use `t` as a variable name: it is the name of a built in function.

Answer (score 0):

To know the "type" of variable use:

```
class(t)
class(a)
```

But notice you are already setting your `matrix7` as `table` here: `t <- table(matrix7)` while your variable `a` is an `integer`.

To get the most common element on your variable (t in your case):

```
sort(table(as.vector(t)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to know the "type" (more properly called the *class*) of an object, use the function `class`:

```
> class(t)
[1] "table"
```

There are a few ways you can find the most frequent value. Given that you have already calculated the `which.max`, you can take the corresponding `name` of `t`:

```
> as.numeric(names(t)[a])
[1] 5 ## I have a different random number seed to you :)
```

Note that you can't just take `t[a]` since that might return an integer code (factors are integers underneath, and the integer might not be what you expect).

In your example, the object `a` is an integer vector of length one. The "data" is 18, and it has the "name" 19. Hence another and perhaps simpler way to get the most frequent value is to take `names(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `class()` to get the the class attribute of an R object or `typeof()` to get the type or storage mode.

Class and type of `a` are `'integer'`, the class of `t` is `'table'` and the type is `'integer'`.

Note that a is a named integer, this is why 2 values are printed. If you use `names(a)` it will only return the value (as a character) of `a`.

If you use `which.max(tabulate(matrix7))` it will return the value without the need to change it further.

```
which.max(tabulate(matrix7))
[1] 16
```

(Side node: since no seed is in your code the result differs, you can set it using `set.seed(x)` where x is an integer).

Comment: I don't think the OP is looking for the answer "16" — I expect the desired answer is "19" (most common value). the 16 arises due to factor coding (some values are absent)